# encryption of the war using Spring

Tags: encryption

I hava met some problems .
I want to encrypt the war using Spring by a tool named ClassGuard ,but when I deploy it to Tomcat and started to launch it , some problems(seemed to be  A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment) arised .

have anyone used ClassGuard  and met problems like this?

please help me...thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Although without the exception we can only speculate, the [ClassGuard FAQ](http://zenofx.com/classguard/) section clearly states that:

> As of Version 1.5, ClassGuard supports Tomcat containers.
>        To use ClassGuard in combination with tomcat, you have to configure your web application for using the ClassGuard tomcat class
>   loader. This can be set in the context of the web application.

So make sure that:

1. You are using the latest stable version.
2. You are using the appropriate class loader.

A probably (although not sure if it is what you are after) easier way to discourage usage of your code would be through [Obfuscation Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29) such as [these](http://java-source.net/open-source/obfuscators).

Comment: yeah,I am using ClassGuard Version 4.0,and I also configure the web application for using the ClassGuard tomcat class loader according to its "Quick Start Guide". As you said Obfuscation was in my consideration at start ,but the leader demand to use encryption.

Comment: have you used this tool ? In fact , WebApp not using Spring can successfully be deployed and accessed,the key problem does focused on Spring. and about ClassLoader i even know little.

Comment: @long Take a look at [this](http://download.zenofx.com/classguard/ClassGuardQuickStart.pdf) PDF file it should shed some light. Unfortunately I have never used this product before.